# RPM Spec file seeing single command as two?

Tags: rpm, docker

I'm having an odd issue with my spec file. I realize that my spec file is entirely improper but I am not here for a lecture.

Within it, I have the following line:

```
sudo docker exec -d tomcat cp /opt/tomcats/* /opt/tomcat/
```

but when I run this, it treats `sudo docker exec -d tomcat` and `cp /opt/tomcats/* /opt/tomcat/` as two separate commands.

Any way to work around this? Thank you.

Comment: How do you know it is running them as separate commands?  In theory those should be separate commands: one is run by sudo and the other by docker (after being passed as arguments from sudo).

Comment: In the verbose output it shows them running separately and when I check the container, the file wasn't copied.

Comment: What did you expect it to do?  "docker exec" runs a command on the container....

Comment: Yes, but it didn't run on the container is my point...